# Confused on a fundamental operation on trees

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

How do we insert a *key* in a binary tree (**not** a BST)?
I mean a binary tree does not have some property of nodes like a BST so it seems that an insertion of a key could be *anywhere* in the tree.
Nevertheless by placing the key anywhere the binary tree could degenerate it to a "list" losing its `O(logN)` properties.
I have seen creation of binary trees using a merge scheme (example application is a `Huffman Tree`) but don't seem to have encountered an insert approach for a binary tree.
This question I believe extends to multiway trees since a binary tree would be a specific example case of a multiway trees (2 children nodes), right?
Am I wrong on this? Is there a specific approach to add a new key to a binary tree or are the applications of a binary tree so specific that a merge operation suffices and there is no need for insertion method?  Perhaps I have missed the usage applications or concept of a BT completely?

**Note:** I am asking about binary trees. ***Not*** about binary **search** trees.

---

**Update:**
If insert could be in any place what is the meaning of term: `Full Binary Tree`?
This implies log properties that can not be achieved by inserting anywhere. Is "Full BT" a definition that is not meaningfull as well?

Comment: A binary tree could be used for anything. There's no natural ordering or interpretation of the elements per se; it's just a tree with two children on each node, possibly null, and usually with a value associated with each node. As you point out, you have to constrain the operations you do on the tree to get any useful properties. Inserting nodes in specials ways can guarantee that the depth of the tree is limited, so you get O(log N) lookups, for example. You have to choose though what goals you have, and algorithms you need to use on the tree to get them.

Comment: O(log N) for doing what? How could an unordered tree have a consistent big O? There are no constraints on organization, so big O is somewhat meaningless, no?

Comment: @DaveNewton:In this case why not just use a list and avoid all the tree logic in the first place?Otherwise why/when do we use a binary tree?

Comment: @NicholasWilson:Then besides a `Hufman Tree` or an expression tree, it seems to me that a binary tree is not of any use. We might as well use a list and simplify things.Otherwise what are other application usages of a BT?

Comment: @user384706 If you have a *completely* degenerate case, then I *wouldn't* use a binary tree, but if you don't know before you start, then a BT is more general (and not overly-complex). Re: "full BT"'s meaning depends on what you're reading, but just because you *can* insert anywhere doesn't mean you *will* insert anywhere.

Comment: Binary trees are hugely useful! They're used for data structures like sets, multisets, associative arrays, and more. Loads of standard library data structures are implemented generally using binary trees, as well as more specific algorithms like finding Huffman encodings. Nothing's of use without being handled correctly: you have to hold a knife the right way up to cut stuff with it, and you have to insert elements sensibly into a binary tree to get fast lookup. Doesn't stop either of them from being massively useful.

Comment: @DaveNewton:`If you have a completely degenerate case`. What does this mean? Are you referring to the data? Also what do you mean:`just because you can insert anywhere doesn't mean you will insert anywhere`? Where would I insert?Do you imply some policy?

Comment: Re: "Full BTs" Of course the definition's meaningful! It means each node has 0 or 2 children. You look at a binary tree, inspect the nodes, and the definition's clear enough to work out whether the tree is full or not. Sorry, @user384706, but it's just not clear what you're getting at.

Comment: @NicholasWilson:Well, this contradits the answer of @tskuzzy which considers them as not that usefull.Also I am not sure how they are used as `Sets`. In java a `Set` is either backed by a `HashMap` or by a `BST` flavor.Not a BT. So I am not sure what you mean here

Comment: @NicholasWilson:I am not truying to get anywhere.I am only studying and wanted to clear this up in my head.

Comment: @user384706 A completely degenerate case is precisely what you're describing--essentially a linked list, where each node has a single child. I'm not sure I understand your second question--a binary tree may have *any* insertion semantics, and need not be explicitly key-based, nor balanced, nor anything. When tskuzzy says there is "no correct way to insert" that doesn't imply it's "always random", it means unlike a BST, which *does* have a single correct way to insert, there is no single correct way to use a BT. I think you're over-thinking this.

Comment: @DaveNewton:`a binary tree may have any insertion semantics, and need not be explicitly key-based` What would be an example application of a such a Binary Tree? Perhaps because I don't know some application I am confused

Comment: @user384706 A directed graph may be a non-key-based binary tree. Insertion is based on arbitrary graph properties (like "I put a node here"), each vertex will have a degree of three or less (the binary part), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Binary trees are a specific type of tree, satisfying the condition that each node has exactly 0, 1, or 2 children. Any tree satisfying this condition is labelled a binary tree.

As such, there is no "correct" way to insert an element into a binary tree. As long as it's a binary tree before, and a binary tree afterwards, the insertion is valid.

The term **binary tree** is more for classification than anything. In its pure "abstract" form, it is not terribly useful as a data structure. However it's helpful when characterizing other, more specific types of trees like the [Huffman tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) as you mentioned.

Comment: To be pedantic a binary tree node can have 0, 1, or 2 children.

Comment: For a full binary tree every node has always 2 children, except the leaves which don't have children.

Comment: @PetarMinchev:But how can we get a full binary tree (which implies logarithmic properties) if insertion could be anywhere? Answer here says `no correct way to insert`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest scheme would probably be to maintain a complete tree as follows. Call the first inserted node 1, the second 2, the third 3, and so on. When you insert node i, make it the left child of node of i/2 if i is even, and the right child of (i-1)/2 if i is odd. For instance, you make the fifth node you insert into the right child of the second one. The sixth node you insert you make into the left child of the third one. If you need to remove a node, exchange it with the highest-numbered one first, so that you always remove from the end.

This tree can be represented by just laying out the nodes in an array starting at position 1, as is common for a binary heap. The children of node i are always 2i and 2i+1, unless these numbers are greater than the total number of nodes, in which case you are at the bottom of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what all that means. In BST the insertion is guided by the element's properties (bigger than, smaller than, etc). In a general BT *you* will have to take care of the insertion process.

Let's say you want to use BT to implement unordered collection. Just label each node with two additional values, besides the data element that it carries: the amount of nodes on the left, and the amount on the right. Then let your insertion be guided by these two, achieving near perfect balance. For leaves, use Nodes without children initially, into which any new element can be inserted as a child, when it arrives.

Now you have a perfectly auto-balancing BT implementing an unordered collection of stuff, which can be inserted into in O(log(n)) time, and can be listed in no particular order. That's just one example.